# URL for crashlytics mapping upload on Android

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

```
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
135 actionable tasks: 135 executed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileAccRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Unknown error while sending file, check network [/app/app/build/crashlytics/AccRelease/mappings/98ad228a679b41d79eced451f3b98015.gz; response: 403 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden]
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 7m 45s
Cleaning up file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I'm trying to build an app from command line in an isolted environment where all URLs have to be whitelisted. My build fails on a moment when crashlytics mapping file has to be uploaded. There's no specific URL listed even when calling --info or --debug. How can I find out where the file gets uploaded?

Comment: Have you found the solution to this?

Comment: yes, crashlytics had to be whitelisted by our devops on the buildserver

Comment: Thanks for you response. Could you say the host which had to be whitelisted?

Comment: I can't remember. You need to run build script e.g. gradle with a flag to print the details of the script e.g. with --info and see which http call failed